# disable env variable substitution in docker compose env files

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I updated docker and notice a significant change of behavior when using my env files in docker-compose

I have the following:

```
env_file:
      - ./file.env
```

and, in `file.env`

```
property=${something}
```

Before updating, doing `echo $property` in my running container would produce the string `${something}`. Which was what I wanted.

Now (docker 19.03.12), `$property` is empty because docker is trying to find `$something` from my system env variables.

What caused this change of behavior? Is there a way to disable it or work around it?

Comment: It seems that these changes were introduced between versions 1.24.0 and 1.28.2.